# Spyder IDE Not Starting from Icon

Tags: python, ide, spyder, launch

I installed Spyder (Version: 5.4.5) by downloading the installation executable from the official Spyder web-site (https://www.spyder-ide.org/), as I want to keep the installation as clean as possible. However, Spyder will not launch when clicking on the Spyder icon.

I have followed all the remedies suggested under the troubleshooting web-pages "Basic First Aid" (https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/basic-first-aid.html) and "Emergency CPR" (https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/emergency-cpr.html) with no success. Spyder will still not launch when clicking on the Spyder icon.

The only way for me to start Spyder seems to be via the terminal (i.e. Powershell) by giving the command "python Spyder.launch.pyw". Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Many thanks in advance.